# Get values from wildcard sub-domain and the url using mod_rewrite

Tags: mod-rewrite, wildcard-subdomain

I have tried for many days to solve my need. Try to find in google and read at the stackoverflow, but I stil unable to get my answer.
I need to get the subdomain value including the value behind it.

for example:

```
subdomain_name.domain.com -> will execute domain.com/user.php?subdomain_value=subdomain_name
subdomain_name.domain.com/product_1.html --> will open page domain.com/user.php?page=1&subdomain_value=subdomain_name
```

I have tried to use code below:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^((?!www\.)[^.]+)\.domain\.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/user\.php$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /user.php?subdomain_value=%1

RewriteRule ^product_([0-9]+).html$ /user.php?process=list_produk&page=$1&subdomain=%1
```

But it failed. When try to open subdomain_name.domain.com/product_1.html, it will keep opening the content of subdomain_name.domain.com

If I removed the code:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /user.php?subdomain_value=%1
```

Then, subdomain_name.domain.com/product_1.html will open the correct page, but the address subdomain_name.domain.com fail to open the correct page.

so, How can I make all of the .htaccess code work fine? I have think very hard and try all possibilities, including added [L], [NC,L], [L,QSA], but all of them failed.
Please help.
Thanks.